# width/height + padding: как задать точные размеры объектов?

Tags: css

Задаю ширину и высоту объекта. Если добавляю к объекту свойство `padding`, то его величина плюсуется с шириной/высотой. [В итоге объект становится шире и длиннее (см. пример)](http://jsfiddle.net/VksUn/).

Как зафиксировать `width` и `height`, чтоб если указано, к примеру, 100px, то и отображается 100px независимо от `padding`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Но поддержка не во всех браузерах корректна. Проверьте в интересующих вас браузерах.

**UPDATE:** так же обратите внимание на свойства:

```
-moz-box-sizing //Firefox

-webkit-box-sizing //Safari, Chrome и iOS
```